# How to get the current Title of a button in Swift 3.0 , ios using sender.titleForState(.Normal)!

Tags: ios, uibutton, swift3, title

I tried to get the `title` of a `button` in swift like below.

```
@IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: Any) {
  let buttonTitle = sender.titleForState(.Normal)!
}
```

but it didn't work,even it doesn't give any `hint` when we press `.` after the sender.

> so what is the correct way of doing this in swift 3.0

Or else if we create an `IBOutlet` and then we use its `currentTitle`, it works fine like below. Why we cannot get it with `sender.` for above

```
@IBOutlet var thebutton: UIButton!

@IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: Any) {
  let buttonTitle = thebutton.currentTitle!
  print(buttonTitle)
}
```

Comment: Change sender to `UIButton`.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Because parameter *sender* is in type `Any` instead of `UIButton`. Change the method signature to:

```
@IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
  if let buttonTitle = sender.title(for: .normal) {
    print(buttonTitle)
  }
}
```

and you should be good to go.

Comment: yep this is working, but you have to unwrap it like below
 `let buttonTitle = sender.title(for: .normal)!`. thanx for the help.

Comment: just to know I'm asking, why should we check if button title has a value(for nil), we know it has a value, so we can simply `unwrap` instead of checking `nil`.

Comment: Yes, if you are sure it isn't nil then use `!` instead of `if let` clause. I personally avoid using `!` as much as possible as it makes your code vulnerable to unexpected exceptions like the ones caused by unwrapping a nil optional.

Comment: thanx in advance :)

Comment: This is working but if in the meantime you have programmatically changed the title of the button, you get the original title and not the current title. To recover the current title you should do : let buttonActualTitle = myButton.titleLabel?.text

Answer (score 11):

Smartest version using Swift 5.0:

```
@IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print(sender.currentTitle)
}
```

Comment: Here I am getting "Cannot assign to immutable expression of type '@lvalue String??'"

Answer (score 6):

To get the title of the button regardless of its current state in swift 3.0 try using this:

```
    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender:UIButton){
       let buttonTitle = sender.titleLabel?.text
       print("\(String(describing: buttonTitle)")
    }
```

This will return the title for the state, based on the state that the button is current in.

Answer (score 3):

In order to resolve the warning, following code may be used.

```
@IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
      let buttonTitle = sender.title(for: .normal) ?? String()
      print(buttonTitle)
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Swift version 5.5.2, the best way I found out to print a label's title is:

```
@IBAction func keyPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print(sender.title(for: .normal)!)
}
```

I was receiving a warning while using `sender.title(for: .normal)`. The exclamation mark (!) solved it.

Answer (score 1):

The simple way just to use currentTitle:

@IBAction func hardlessSelected(_ sender: UIButton) {

```
    print(sender.currentTitle)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
  let title = sender.title(for: .normal)
  print("\(title) button pressed")
}
```

So this is for swift 4.0, not the last one.

Answer (score 0):

If your button has a regular title you can use:

`button.title(for: state) // probably UIControl.State.normal`

If your `UIButton` has an attributed title you'll need to use:

`self.attributedTitle(for: state)`

Or you can use a more general extension:

```
extension UIButton {
    func titleForState(_ state: UIControl.State = .normal) -> String? {
        if let title = self.title(for: state) {
            return title
        }

        if let attribTitle = self.attributedTitle(for: state) {
            return attribTitle.string
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used switch statment:

var buttonConter = 1
@IBAction func hardlessSelected(_ sender: UIButton) {

```
    switch buttonConter {
    case 1:
        buttonConter += 1
        print("Soft")
    case 2:
        buttonConter += 1
        print("Medium")
    case 3:
        buttonConter += 1
        print("Hard")
    default:
        print("Non")
    }

    
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `currentTitle` of the `UIButton` to get the name, you can use `titleLabel`.

The easy way to get this done is to unwrap the `titleLabel` then unwrap the `text`:

```
@IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    var buttonTitle = sender.titleLabel!.text!
    print(buttonTitle)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Since Swift 3.0, it changed from

sender.titleForState(.Normal)! >> sender.title(for : .normal)!

Change **Any** to **AnyObject**.

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
  let title = sender.title(for: .normal)!
  print("\(title) button pressed")
}
```

Comment: AnyObject doesn't have a method `title(for:)`.

Answer (score -4):

```
  @IBAction func btnNextTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    let title = (sender as AnyObject).title(for: .normal)!
  }
```

Swift4.0